# Trigger Laravel 5.4 reset password programatically from controller

Tags: laravel-5.4

I need to use Laravel's out-of-the-box reset password functionality through another function in my API controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ResetPasswords trait in your controller.

```
class ApiController extends Controller 
{
    use \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

    public function doSomething(Request $request) {
        ...
        $this->broker()->sendResetLink(['email' => 'youremail@yourdomain.com']);
    }
}
```